# Detect Apple Subscription Expiration

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

I want to detect that customer's subscription now over / complete so I can remove facilities I was providing to them.

On each launch of application, I have following kind of details from Apple Subscription:

```
public void CheckIfSubscriptionIsActive(){
    ConfigurationBuilder builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());
    // Get a reference to IAppleConfiguration during IAP initialization.
    IAppleConfiguration appleConfig = builder.Configure<IAppleConfiguration>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (appleConfig.appReceipt)) {
        Debug.Log (appleConfig.appReceipt);
//            InstantiateDebugText (DebugInfoPanel, "APP Receipt Base64 " + appleConfig.appReceipt);
        var receiptData = System.Convert.FromBase64String (appleConfig.appReceipt);
//            InstantiateDebugText (DebugInfoPanel, "receipt Data "+ receiptData);
        AppleReceipt receipt = new AppleValidator (AppleTangle.Data ()).Validate (receiptData);
        InstantiateDebugText (DebugInfoPanel, "Apple receipt " + receipt);
        foreach (AppleInAppPurchaseReceipt productReceipt in receipt.inAppPurchaseReceipts) {
            Debug.Log ("PRODUCTID: " + productReceipt.productID);
            Debug.Log ("PURCHASE DATE: " + productReceipt.purchaseDate);
            Debug.Log ("EXPIRATION DATE: " + productReceipt.subscriptionExpirationDate);
            Debug.Log ("CANCELDATE DATE: " + productReceipt.cancellationDate);
            InstantiateDebugText (DebugInfoPanel, "PRODUCTID: " + productReceipt.productID);
            InstantiateDebugText (DebugInfoPanel, "PURCHASE DATE: " + productReceipt.purchaseDate);
            InstantiateDebugText (DebugInfoPanel, "EXPIRATION DATE: " + productReceipt.subscriptionExpirationDate);
            InstantiateDebugText (DebugInfoPanel, "CANCELDATE DATE: " + productReceipt.cancellationDate);
        }
    }
```

Because in detection of subscription expiration calculation, I can't take help of current iPhone date and time and my app was not using any of custom server related things so I am totally dependent on Apple for this.

Because only this reason I was using Auto Renewable Subscription so that I have information regarding subscription duration.

Now please share your thought regarding this, how to detect subscription is expired now?

Answer (score 3):

You should valdate yoru receipt with Appstore first.
use receipt data you are getting from following:

```
var receiptData = System.Convert.FromBase64String (appleConfig.appReceipt);
```

You can check how to validate receipt with apple server from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html)

However, don't relay on status received from status. for autoreniew receipt, it will return success even if receipt is valid but expired.
In response, you will get receipts. Loop through all receipts, check for "expires_date" field for product id = your required product id. "expires_date" will contain [epoch time.](http://www.epochconverter.com/) . You can check if this date is greater than current date and  if you found any receipt where (productid = yourproducid && expireDate > currentEpocDate) , subscription is valid. else its expired or stopped or not purchased.

Create json,

```
  {
    "receipt-data": "receiptData (string))"
}
```

and post it to apple's server - ( https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt). In response, You will get receipt with validaton status.

Note:

> In the test environment, use
>   https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt as the URL. In
>   production, use https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt as the URL.

Comment: thanks for your awesome reply. Let me ask other doubts, 1) for checking of subscription expiration, we have to query our custom server? 2) Subscription expiration information can we fetch from directly apple? rather than remain dependant on custom server?

Comment: You can directly check on apple server for subscription status. Even if you use custom server, your custom server need to send request to apple server for validating receipt.  as I have added in note : You can use given url for validating and please check https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html  once.

Comment: above you have given comparison of expire date and current date for validation of subscription purpose, this is for which purpose? if apple is replying me about subscription status as per your last message. This thing confuse me. Because without custom server I can't take current iphone date for validating subscription.

Comment: 1) As per link I shared (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html)  -- Apple gives you validity or receipt -so, even if receipt is expired but valid, it will return success.

Comment: 2) Why you need custom server to get iphone's current date?

Comment: Try sending request to apple's server with your receipt data, when you will see response, It will be easier to understand.

Comment: On receipt I got an expire date and I want to compare current date with expire date to know whether current subscription active or not, what I should consider as current date? i.e. iPhone date or custom server date

Comment: iphone date as current date.

Comment: Receipt expire date is based on GMT+0.  iphone date also gives you GTM+0 date by default.

Comment: What if any person change his iPhone date? what effect it will create on subscription?